# how to access table inside a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

i got a table inside a table like

```
<table class="xyz">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>hello<label>
<input></input>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

i want to get the inside table elements using jquery

Comment: Are you still having difficulties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$('table.xyz table')... // It will select the <table> which is inside of <table>
                        // with the class xyz
```

If you meant by `inside table elements` to all of the elements:

```
$('table.xyz table *')... // It will select all the elements that inside the 
                          // <table>with the class xyz which is inside of <table>
```

If you want only the inputs:

```
$('table.xyz table input')...
```

`descendant selector` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Change the width of `<td>` in that table:

```
$('table.xyz table td').css('width' ,'300px');
```

Comment: what if i want to change the td width of inside table ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example it would be

```
$('table.xyz table')
```

The first part 'table.xyz' will select the upper table (table with a class xyz) and then the second part will select any child with a table tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method from jQuery.

Comment: Why create new jQuery object if you can use a better selector from the first place?

Comment: If you will have another table on that page you can get the one you need, with class="xyz".

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="xyz" id="xyz">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#xyz tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
        $(this).find("input").each( function( index, item ) {
              alert(index+"----"+$(this).val() );
        });
    }); 
});
```